# C# Forms reference a image with [i]

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I would like to distribute images from an imageList on to several picture boxes.
I am unsure of how to iterate through the picture boxes efficiently.
Here is what i am picturing and unable to find a solution for.
The pictureBox's are pictureBox1-5

````
      {
        pictureBox[i].Image = imageList1.Images[i];
      }```
ik this will  not work as the pictureBox name is a string. But feel this will help show what i am looking to work out.
````

Comment: `var pbs = this.Controls.TypeOf<PictureBox>().ToArray()` ? -- ***Disclaimer*** : May contain typos, traces of nuts and be completely wrong, I am not responsible for the people you maim or otherwise harm with this code

Comment: `The pictureBox's are pictureBox1-5`  Almost certainly not true

Comment: @TheGeneral typo of OfType?

Comment: @CaiusJard nice catch :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all your pictureboxes are added directly to the main form (ie they aren't inside a panel, groupbox or similar) you can index the controls collection by string name. If you thus have names of pictureBox1 thru 5:

```
(this.Controls[$"pictureBox{i+1}"] as PictureBox).Image = imageList1.Images[i];
```

If they're in a panel, then they'll be a part of that panel's controls collection instead of the main form's. If they're in different panels, bit more of a headache. Use the below instead, for ease

---

You could also add them to a class level array in eg the constructor

```
private PictureBox _pbs;

ctor(...){

  InitializeComponent();

  _pbs = new []{ pictureBox1, pictureBox2, ... pictureBox5 };
}
```

And then use that..